Convert JSON String to Unity C# String - Not Deserializing, Not Converting Into An Object
I have looked everywhere for the answer to this. I have a complicated, serializable Unity object, which captures various pieces of information (including complicated nested objects) about touchscreen events. For various reasons, especially performance, I cannot save the object directly into a list and send up the data and properties for this object up to my back-end.
Therefore, I have opted to save a serialized version of this object and send it up to my database. However, my database seems to store escaped JSON when I store the object as serialized JSON. There are 1) double quotes after the brackets that open up the object; and then quotes separating every object in the JSON array.
For example:["{"eventID":"2e9586d27f2e2257adc87e1ec1f437... "] and then " " encapsulating individual other objects in the array.
All I am trying to do is to convert a serializable object into plaintext basically. How do I do this? I have tried doing everything - trimming, replacing letters in the string, converting to a byte array and de-converting. I simply want to find a method of storing the object and its properties as a string; converting everything into a dictionary would be hugely time-consuming, and I think it would be best if I just figured out a way of easily converting to valid JSON from here.
How can I get it to look like this: [{"color": null, "end_pos": null, "end_time":..."? Thanks for any help!
CODE is here:
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newTouch);
allTouches.Add(jsonString); 


newTouch is of type TouchEvent.

TouchEvent uses [System.Serializable]. Should I not be serializing this object again? If not, how do I use it and store it in a List of strings?
EDIT: Added a picture. As you can see the events in the first few rows are ones where the object is stored. The events below are ones where the json string is stored. I want them to be escaped, and in the right valid format, but they're not. Is there perhaps a way of taking how the object would be stored and making that into a string?


"my database seems to store escaped JSON when I store the object as serialized JSON" Can you show us an example of this? Where do you see it? Is it possible it's only an artefact of these?

JSON is serialized text with a specific format, so as serialized JSON is unclear. Databases don't escape it, to them text is text is text. It seems the real problem is application code that tries to serialize an already serialized JSON string, thus escaping it

Post data as text and add your code. What you posted is a list of plain old strings, that just happen to contain already serialized JSON. That's an application bug. If you serialize List<Color> and save it to the database you'll get [{"red":123,"green":200,"blue":15},{"red":123,"green":200,"blue":15} not ["{\"red\":123...]. Somehow the *application serialized each Color to a string, then tried to serialize List<string>

@phuzi Added a picture.

@cinnamonrollapplecider pictures can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled. What you posted suggest the application has a bug, not that there's anything wrong with the database or C#.

It looks like some of the data were already strings before being serialized to JSON

In fact, it seems that some code is properly saving JSON strings and some other code is performing double serialization. The first two lines, which I can't copy because it's not text, are proper JSON. That alone proves the problem isn't the database at all

@PanagiotisKanavos So I am converting the object into a serialized version properly? And the hypothesis is that it is being doubly serialized somewhere else?

Is there a way to simply turn it into a string literal, though?

Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos. You were right. I did some digging and was able to locate the source of the issue.
